# Error when running python script on remote machine using Fabric's run command

Tags: python, fabric

From a remote machine A, I am trying to run a python script hosted on a remote machine B using Fabric's run function. However, the following error shows up.

I have tried changing env.shell to machine B's "which python" directory but it did not work.

```
with cd('/opt/app/transfer_learning'):
    run("python script.py")
```

The expected result is to see the script being executed which will upload something to MongoDB in which I will listen for changes. However, the following error pops up:

```
[3.0.40.214] run: python script.py
[3.0.40.214] out: /bin/bash: python: command not found
[3.0.40.214] out:


Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 127 while executing!

Requested: python script.py
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /opt/app/transfer_learning >/dev/null && python script.py"
```

Comment: try with `/full/path/to/python` if only machine B has installed Python.

Comment: @furas machine B's python directory is located using "which python" command right? I have changed the env.shell to that directory, however now it is causing this error instead: Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 2 while executing!

Comment: don't change env.shell - use `/full/path/python script.py`. You can get full path using `which python`. Eventually in bash should works `$(which python) script.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you furas for the solution. I used "/full/path/to/python script.py" instead in the run() function and it worked.